# Помогите с пунктуацией! Как обособляются слова "кажется" и "нет"?

Tags: пунктуация

Я была... Но как мне кажется нет разницы куда идти.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему, можете отметить его галочкой (под серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

*Как мне кажется* — это вводное предложение, которое необходимо выделить запятыми:
*Но, как мне кажется, нет разницы, куда идти.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123

*Куда идти* — это придаточное предложение, перед которым нужна запятая.